# Communicate changes to top-level Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a top-level Makefile that is recursively calling a sub-level makefile. Because of this, the sub-Makefile is defined as a `.PHONY` target:

```
top-target: sub-target
    some commands

.PHONY: sub-target
sub-target:
    $(MAKE) -C dir/to/sub/makefile
```

Because of this, `top-target` is always built regardless of whether if `sub-target` changed or not. Is there a way to communicate whether if the `sub-target` changed?

One thing I can do is remove `sub-target` as a `.PHONY` and use some kind of stamp, but `sub-target` has its own dependencies and a simple stamp could cause false positive builds. Unless I manually move the entire `sub-target` Makefile into the top-level Makefile, it'd be difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.  Of course, it's usually more efficient to have all your targets build in a single instance of make rather than using sub-makes but it can be done.

First, your `top-target` should not depend on `sub-target`; it should depend on the actual output generated by the `sub-target` makefile that it needs to rebuild.

Then you can write a rule for those targets, which does nothing, but which depends on the `sub-target`.  Like this:

```
top-target: libsubtarget.a
        some commands

libsubtarget.a: sub-target ;

.PHONY: sub-target
sub-target:
        $(MAKE) -C dir/to/sub/makefile
```

Be sure you include the `;` after the `libsubtarget.a`, otherwise it won't work.

By creating a "do-nothing" rule you've created a buffer between `top-target` and `sub-target`.  `sub-target` will always be rebuilt, but `top-target` will only be rebuilt if `libsubtarget.a` actually changes its modification time, even though `sub-target` is always run.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. How is `sub-target` triggered? There's no target calling `sub-target` to produce `libsubtarget.a`. How will Makefile know that `sub-target` is the one responsible for producing `libsubtarget.a`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed something.  Fixed.

Comment: Now *I* am slightly confused. As `libsubtarget.a` is dependent on a phony target, the rule for it will always trigger and thus internally `make` will always think that it updated `libsubtarget.a`, therefore executing `top-target` on each run as well, no? At least on my GNUmake the test is hinting towards this behaviour.

Comment: I was under the impression that this is the behavior as well @Vroomfondel

Comment: No.  I mean yes, you're right, the rule for building `libsubtarget.a` will always run.  But that recipe is a no-op (empty), so it never does anything.  It's not the case that just because make runs a rule, it _assumes_ that the rule updates the target.  Even after make runs a rule, it will still use the actual modified time of the target file to decide whether targets depending on it are out of date.  You'll see many, many recipes out there (even in POSIX makefiles) that check for changes and only update targets if the file contents actually change to avoid excessive rebuilds.

Comment: So in the case where nothing needs to be done: `top-target` depends on `libsubtarget.a`, which depends on `sub-target`.  `sub-target` is phony so it always runs and the sub-make runs, but since nothing needs to be done it doesn't update `libsubtarget.a` and exits.  Make sees the phony rule so it runs the recipe of `libsubtarget.a`, which does nothing and exits.  Then make compares the mod time on `libsubtarget.a` against `top-target` and sees that it doesn't need to rebuild `top-target`, so it does nothing.

Comment: I tried to explain this, perhaps in too-few words, in the last paragraph of my answer.